# Markup text in container that equals String with jquery

Tags: jquery

I want to markup every element inside a table that equals a given input(e.g if I type "asd" and inside my table I'd have a word "wasdfa" the asd would get marked up).I do know how to make things slide in and out onclick etc. but I have no idea how to check textstrings in a potentially infinite table of content with jquery.Are there loops?How could I get this done?

Comment: Please define *would get marked up*.

Comment: Highlighting techniques depend on the complexity of your content. If you have plain text, than it's easy. If you have tags like `<b>`, `<i>`, `<a>` etc inside your content the task is a bit harder to accomplish. If that's the case, this has been already answered on Stackoverflow.

Comment: Uhm I don't really understand your comment^^The basic idea is that I want something like if you use Ctrl + F in chrome and you type in a word or some letters they get marked up.

Comment: A table cell can contain TAGS (Hopefully you know what tags are right?) My question is IF your cells contain pure text or is populated by HTML tags like *Lorem **some bold text** ipsum*

Comment: I was referring to @MrUpsidown in my other comment.They contain only plain text.

Comment: Ugh sorry I totally misunderstood the question at first in my answer - basically look at the jquery `.find()` selector page and at the bottom there's an example of what you are trying to do I believe.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a regular expression. Use `jQuery.each()` to iterate through all table cells.

**HTML**:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>xxx xxx</td>
        <td>asd xxx</td>
        <td>xxx asd</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>asd</td>
        <td>xxxasdxxx</td>
        <td>asd asd</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

**CSS**:

```
.yellow {
    background-color: yellow;
}
```

**JS**:

```
$('table td').each(function () {

    $(this).html($(this).text().replace(/asd/g, '<span class="yellow">asd</span>'));
});
```

`/asd/g` will look for the string "asd" and `g` makes it global (in case there are multiple matches in one cell). It replaces it with the same string, adding a `<span>` tag of class `yellow` around it.

<kbd>[JSFiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/upsidown/g448k9hL/)</kbd>

**Edit:** If you want to make it dynamic, you can use a [`RegExp`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp) object.

```
$('input').on('input', function () {

    replaceString($(this).val());
});

function replaceString(str) {

    var re = new RegExp(str, "g");

    $('table td').each(function () {

        $(this).html($(this).text().replace(re, '<span class="yellow">' + str + '</span>'));
    });
}
```

<kbd>[JSFiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/upsidown/g448k9hL/1/)</kbd>

Answer (score -1):

You can markup searched text easily using jquery. Here I have given a demo using keyup method of jquery. I have included a span with background color to mark the searched string inside the table.

```
<html>
<head>
    <style>
        span{
            color: white;
            background: red;
        }
    </style>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<input type="text" id="search" placeholder="Enter your search string"/>
<br><br>
<div id="result"></div>
<table border="1">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Header 1</th>
            <th>Header 2</th>
            <th>Header 3</th>
            <th>Header 4</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>This is me</td>
            <td>This is me</td>
            <td>This is me</td>
            <td>This is me</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>This is me</td>
            <td>This is me</td>
            <td>This is me</td>
            <td>This is me</td>
        </tr>

    </tbody>
</table>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("#search").on("keyup",function(){
            $val=$("#search").val();
            $replace_text="<span>"+$val+"</span>";
            $("td, th").each(function(){
                $td_val=$(this).text();
                $td_val=$td_val.replace($val,$replace_text);
                $(this).html($td_val);
            });
        });
    });
</script>
</body>
```

Comment: Not bad, but that won't be very flexible. And it won't allow multiple matches of the same string in the same cell.